# Sending JSON with enum data types

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enums, ebay-api

I am trying to send a json with a data type that is a enum according to the ebay documantion here:

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/api-ref/inventory/types/OperatingHours.html

The field in question is the dayOfWeekEnum, which I tried sending in my JSON several ways:

```
{"dayOfWeekEnum": "FRIDAY"}
{"dayOfWeekEnum": 0}
{"dayOfWeekEnum": {"dayOfWeekEnum": "FRIDAY"}}
```

And none of them didn't work. I alwyas get the message saying it could not serialize the field `dayOfWeekEnum`:

```
[{"errorId"=>2004, "domain"=>"ACCESS", "category"=>"REQUEST", "message"=>"Invalid request", "longMessage"=>"The request has errors. For help, see the documentation for this API.", "parameters"=>[{"name"=>"reason", "value"=>"Could not serialize field [operatingHours.dayOfWeekEnum]"}]}]
```

I am assuming ebay runs a Java api, so how should I send my JSON enum info properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know from experience that eBay's documentation can be wrong when it comes to the names of fields. Have you tried passing **dayOfWeek** instead of dayOfWeekEnum?

Comment: This is it. Unbelievable. I kind of tried it before, but it didn't work I guess because I wasn't ready to isolate the issue.

Comment: Just ran into this. Hasn't been fixed in their documentation yet.